# Is the radical of a Lie algebra preserved by all of its derivations?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional complex Lie algebra. A derivation $D: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ such that for any $a, b \in \mathfrak{g}$, we have $D[a, b] = [Da, b] + [a, Db]$.

Let $\hbox{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})$ be the radical of $\mathfrak{g}$. My question is: does $D$ map $\hbox{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})$ into itself, i.e. is it true that $D(\text{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})) \subset \hbox{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true. Any derivation maps the solvable radical into the nilradical, hence we have
$$
D(rad(\mathfrak{g}))\subseteq nil(\mathfrak{g})\subseteq rad(\mathfrak{g}).
$$
The proof can be found in Jacobson's book on Lie algebras, see Corollary $2$ to 
Theorem $13$ in chapter $II$, section $7$.
Ideals which are invariant under all derivations are called *characteristic ideals*.

Comment: Alternatively, it is Theorem 2.5.13 in David J. Winter's book Abstract Lie Algebras.

Comment: I could not understand the proof given in Jacobson's book on Lie algebras and  David J. Winter's book Abstract Lie Algebras.  Could anyone help me to provide the simplest proof of D(rad(g))  is inside nil(g)? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In the case of finite-dimensional Lie algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ we can argue very straightforwardly as follows:

The radical is clearly characteristic in the sense that it is preserved by all automorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$. Now observe that $D : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is a derivation iff the exponential $\exp(tD) : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is a one-parameter group of automorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$ (in fact $\text{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$ is the Lie algebra of $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$), so this exponential preserves the radical and hence so does its derivative.