# Radical of a Lie algebra is a characteristic ideal

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over a field $F$, not necessary of characteristic $0$. We say that an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \unlhd \mathfrak{g}$ is characteristic if it is stable under any [derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Derivations), i.e. $\delta(\mathfrak{a}) \subseteq \mathfrak{a}$ for any $\delta \in \mathrm{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$. We also denote the radical $\mathfrak{r}(\mathfrak{g})$ to be the (unique) maximal solvable Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

> Is it true that $\mathfrak{r}(\mathfrak{g})$ is a characteristic ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$?

---

I have a few ideas on tackling this problem but were mostly to no avail. The most convincing approach appears to be showing that $\delta(\mathfrak{r}(\mathfrak{g}))$ is solvable, and hence must lie inside the radical. But I can't seem to proceed much further from here. Even if I were to assume $\mathfrak{r}(\mathfrak{g})$ is abelian, the furthest I can go is that given $x,y \in \mathfrak{r}(\mathfrak{g})$:
$$
[\delta(x),\delta(y)] = \delta([\delta(x),y]) - [\delta^2(x),y]
$$
which does not seem to help much.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the radical of a Lie algebra preserved by all of its derivations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686277/is-the-radical-of-a-lie-algebra-preserved-by-all-of-its-derivations).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks, do you know if it's true if we take away the assumption that the corresponding field is not of characteristic $0$?

Comment: The standard proof uses the nondegeneracy of the Killing form of semisimple Lie algebras. This is false in characteristic $p>0$. I think that indeed the result need no longer be true then.